# What martial art can Misaki use?

Tags: maid-sama

My question: what martial art can Misaki Ayuzawa use? I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: According to her character profile in the manga, she is trained in [aikido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aikido).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chapter 3, it is mentioned that Misaki was learning [Aikido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aikido).

[image: Chapter 3 - Conversation about Aikido]

There are various scenes in the first few chapters that shows Misaki using Aikido moves. For example:

- In the middle of chapter 1, Misaki threw a sandbag over her head to clear the way.
- At the beginning of chapter 2, Misaki used Aikido on a male student who was half-naked.
- In the middle of chapter 3, Misaki used Aikido on the members of the student council who slacked off at the beginning of the chapter.
- At the end of chapter 3, Misaki used Aikido on the 2 masochists.